# How to add latest Unity version in Unity HUB?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to add Unity 2018.4.9 version within Unity HUB so I have tried to download the latest Unity 2018 version from the Unity HUB.

But my surprise I can't able to find the latest Unity 2018 any version within the list. Here is the snapshot for this:
[image]

While the actual website has many Unity versions available for Unity 2018 version.
[image]

Now how can I download Unity 2018.4.9 through Unity HUB?

Comment: It's already there, Unity 2018.4.9f1 (LTS)...

Comment: I don't want to use LTS version!!

Comment: What's the problem with LTS?

Comment: Btw if you really dont want to use LTS for some strange reasons, there is 2018.3.14f1 which is the latest non LTS release of 2018...

Comment: Why they have included LTS version? and what is benefit of LTS version?

Comment: LTS = Long Time Support, it means there will be no new features, just bug fixes for that version, so if you need a 2018 version LTS is extremely reccomended

Comment: If you want only a specific version, perhaps download the editor of that version from the website. Once installed, you can add it to Unity Hub under "Installs" and click on "On my machine".

Comment: https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/lts-releases .. `2018.4.9` **is** the LTS version. You can't say: "I want `2018.4.9` but not LTS" ... as people before me already commented: There is absolutely no valid reason why you shouldn't want an LTS version.. it means it is maintained and receives ongoing bug fixes and support... If you really want the **latest** version however which is not LTS than checkout [`2019.2.6`](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2019.2.6) or [`2019.1.14`](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2019.1.14) which have new features included

Comment: I am now aware of all these things before I am not aware of the LTS version. I want to install the latest patch releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

- downloading the version you want from https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive
- Hitting the "Locate" button in UnityHub
- Navigating to the location of the download, highlighting it and clicking "Select Editor"

[location of locate button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dTnF.png)

Comment: glad it helped!

Comment: There is no "Add Module" option - it is not possible to add anything through Unity HUB if you downloaded manually Unity version.

Answer (score 0):

Unityhub supports deep linking like this

[unityhub://2018.4.12f1/59ddc4c59b4f](http://unityhub://2018.4.12f1/59ddc4c59b4f)

Simply click this link and it opens downloading through the hub (if it is not clickable try sending it yourself in some chat app like slack or telegram). But to download any other version you need to find it in here https://unity3d.com/ru/unity/whats-new/2018.4.12 and generate a link using hash at the bottom of that page

```
Changeset: 59ddc4c59b4f
```

So the ida is

```
unityhub:// + version + / + hash
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly download your desired Unity version from here. [link](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) --- [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYQ4q.png)
Then you can go to Unity Hub and under the installs tab you can find the button named "Locate". [Locate Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRwXc.png)

Comment: Your answer has been included [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58883473/6670491). Consider reading other's / accepted answers before attempting to answer an old question (22 months ago).